# how to count of embedded mongodb php?

Tags: php, mongodb

I've the problem with php and MongoDB. Here's my document:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("58d7815f387e76880c000000"),
"receiver" : "Katty",
"chat" : [
                {
                        "sender" : "jhon",
                        "date" : ISODate("2017-03-26T08:53:55Z"),
                        "message" : "Who are you?"
                        "status" : "sent"
                },
                {
                         "sender" : "jhon",
                        "date" : ISODate("2017-03-26T08:53:55Z"),
                        "message" : "What do you want?"
                        "status" : "pending"
                }
                {
                         "sender" : "jhon",
                        "date" : ISODate("2017-03-26T08:53:55Z"),
                        "message" : "Hah ?"
                        "status" : "pending"
                }
]
```

And here's my php program:

```
<?php
$conn = new Mongo();
$db = $conn->selectDB('basarnas');
$query = $db->informasi_bencana;
$nosql = array("_id"=> new MongoId($id), "chat.status"=>"pending");
$result = $query->find($nosql);
$beritasar = $result->count();
$total = $beritasar;
echo "status pending = ".$total;
?>
```

And the result is

```
status pending = 1
```

And I want the result is

```
status pending = 2
```

How to count of embedded document when it has status = "pending" ?

Comment: Because you're fetching the main document (which is only one), not the sub documents. You're query basically says: "Get all documents that has a sub document where status is "pending".

Comment: Yeah, I think so. And what can I do for fetching the sub documents ?

Comment: If you need to be able to query and search the documents in "chat" separately, they should be in their own collection. Just because you _can_ have nested documents doesn't mean it's always a good idea. In my experience, having nested documents will come back and bite you more often than not.

Comment: What do you think bout my documents ? Is it possible to fecthing count of sub documents ? I cannot change my concept of document. :(

Comment: Is there way to count of embedded documents with aggregate like $unwind, $match, $sum, etc but I don't know how to set aggregate in php. :(

Comment: First of all you are using very deprecated mongo library. Secondly, if you filter by _id, no other filters necessary - _id is unique. Lastly, fetching a document, you get all `chat` subdocuments  and can count them on the application level.

Comment: Update your code to use the new MongoDB-library and read the documentation about aggregate.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks for your reference but my MongoDB-library is already support. I just want to know how to implementation aggregate in php because all this time, I just have used find and combining with foreach to get data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unwind the embedded document and then match the status then using groupby count all the documents.

```
db.collection.aggregate([

                        { "$unwind": "$chat"},
                       {$match:{"chat.status": "pending"}}, 
                        { "$group":{"_id":null, count: {$sum:1}}}
                ])
```

OR

Simplify fetch all the documents and count the length of the array

```
db.collection.aggregate([

                        { "$unwind": "$chat"},
                       {$match:{"chat.status": "pending"}}, 

                ])
```