# Using MongoDB aggregations in PHP with the MongoDB/Driver/Manager class

Tags: php, mongodb

I need to perform a MongoDB aggregation in PHP.

I read about the [MongoCollection::aggregate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php) method but to use the [MongoCollection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongocollection.php) class I need to go through the [MongoClient](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php) class, which is deprecated.

In the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php) it is said to use the [MongoDB](https://www.php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php) driver instead and the [MongoDB\Driver\Manager](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-manager.php) class. I already use this class for all my queries, updates and inserts, but I can't find a way to execute aggregations.

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43678442/use-aggregate-method-with-the-new-mongodb-driver-classes-in-php) does not help me because it uses regular queries.

I am quite surprised I can't find any answers out there.

Maybe I am focusing on aggregations while I don't need them so here is what I am trying to do:
I have a `users` collection that contains a `peels` field which is an array of string.
I would like to count for a given user the number of elements of its `peels` field matching a specific regex.

**For instance, if I have this user:**

```json
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5ff337f8415b0000f9003b78"),
  "name": "Foo",
  "peels": [
    "2021-03-08",
    "2021-04-19",
    "2020-07-20",
    "2020-08-10"
  ]
}
```

I want to get the number of dates of the user for the year 2021, so matching the regex `2021-*`.
This should give me `2`.

If this can indeed be solved without aggregations it would still be interesting to know how to use aggregation with the [MongoDB/Driver/Manager](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-manager.php) or any other solution that is not deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php is part of deprecated extension. It's not the client that is deprecated as per https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php, the entire extension is.

The replacement is an extension and a higher-level library. https://www.php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php is the extension. https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/tutorial/ is the library. You should use the library unless you have a specific reason to use the extension.

https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/tutorial/crud/#complex-queries-with-aggregation shows an aggregation example with the library.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunatly I don't have the `MongoDB\Client` class or the `MongoDB\Collection` class availables on my server and I can't change the configuration. I will use queries and PHP to do the math, but your answer seems to be what I was looking for.

Comment: If you are stuck with the old extensions I see no issue with using all of the functionality it provides including aggregations.

Comment: You're right but I don't have the MongoClient class available either. I don't know what exactly was installed on the server but that is definitely not enough.